# How to know what causes a html video start playing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html5-video, dom-events

There is a HTML video tag. I want to know when it starts playing:

- Is it caused by `autoplay`?
- Is it caused by calling `play()` in JavaScript?
- Is it caused by user click on the play button?

I want to deal with *play event* caused **only** by user actions (The third case in above three).

My current solution:

```
function videoEventHandler(ev) {
    var videoElem = ev.target;
    if (!videoElem.controls) {
        // no controls in video, means events can't be caused by user actions
        return true;
    }

    switch (ev.type) {
        case 'play':
            if (videoElem.autoplay && !videoElem.hasPaused) {
                // first play event in autoplay video, muse be caused by autoplay
                return true;
            }
            // deal with play event caused by user actions
            return true;

        case 'pause':
            ev.target.hasPaused = true;
            // deal with pause event caused by user actions
            return true;
    }
}
```

**Problem:** My solution can't handle these scenarios:

- It doesn't know if a *play event* caused by JavaScript call to `play()`
- It doesn't know if a *pause event* caused by video reaches the end

**Please Note:** I can't add a flag on `play()`, because it is called in the web page. The web page is not written by me, and I'm not able to change it. (I'm writing a Chrome extension)

Could anyone help me on this?

This is a very specific question, it may be confusing to somebody. If my question confuses you, please leave a comment and I will try to explain more clearly. Appreciated.

Comment: What if the site provides its own play button separate from the video element? It's a user action basically even though the video is started by play() code.

Comment: @wOxxOm You are right. Seems there is not a perfect solution for every scenario. I just want to cover most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't create video controls of my own. As said in question, *"I'm writing a Chrome extension, and not able to change the web page"*.

**Best solution I got (Not perfect):**

```
function videoEventHandler(ev) {
    var videoElem = ev.target;
    if (!videoElem.controls) {
        // no controls in video, means events can't be caused by user actions
        return true;
    }

    switch (ev.type) {
        case 'play':
            if (videoElem.autoplay && !videoElem.hasPaused) {
                // first play event in autoplay video, muse be caused by autoplay
                return true;
            }
            // deal with play event caused by user actions
            return true;

        case 'pause':
            ev.target.hasPaused = true;
            var self = this;
            Util.setTimeout(function() {
                // we don't record pause event followed by ended, because it is caused by video reaches end
                if (!videoElem.hasEnded) {
                    // deal with pause event caused by user actions
                }
                videoElem.hasEnded = false;
            }, 50);
            return true;
        case 'ended':
            videoElem.hasEnded = true;
            return true;
    }
}
```

> **Please Note:** this answer is not perfect. It don't know the difference between *play event* caused by `autoplay` and by call `play()` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling from javaScript to `play()` just set an attribute in the element as true to specify that it is started by javascript.While listening to `play` event, you can check that variable to know if it is played from javascript.

Before calling play:

```
video.playedFromJavascript=true;
video.play();
```

In play listener:

```
if (videoElem.playedFromJavascript==true) {
                // play event caused by javascript
videoElem.playedFromJavascript=false; // resetting it to false once captured
       }
```

We have `ended` event which triggered when a video reached the end.Use this event to know if a pause event caused by video reaches the end.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say, the web page is not written by me, and I'm not able to change it. (I'm writing a Chrome extension)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hide the default controls and create your own. This way you will get an information about user's actions only.

As far as I know there is no difference between user pressing *play button* and video starting to play due to *autoplay* flag set to *true*.

As the [HTML5 specification](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html#attr-media-autoplay) says:

> The autoplay attribute is a boolean attribute. When present, the user
>   agent will automatically begin playback of the media resource as soon
>   as it can do so without stopping.

Please keep in mind that if the connection is slow a user can press *play* button before the playback will start due to the *autoplay* flag.

To figure out the end of the playback you can use [ended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended) event or try to check the position of the playback (*duration* and *currentTime* attributes).